# Can I apply Cauchy-Goursat to $\int_0^\pi \frac{dz}{3+z^2} \leq \frac\pi3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to prove that  $\int_0^\pi \frac{dz}{3+z^2} \leq \frac\pi3$ I wanted to prove it by directly getting the integral value

I know $$\int_0^\pi \frac{dz}{3+z^2}  =  \int_0^\pi \frac{dz}{z^2-(\sqrt{3i})^2} = \int_0^\pi \frac{dz}{(z-\sqrt{3i})(z+\sqrt{3i})} $$

making $$t=\sqrt{3i} = \sqrt{3}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} = {\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}}(1+i)$$
and using partial fractions we get 
$${\frac{1}{(z+t)(z-t)}} = \frac{A}{(z+t)} + {\frac{B}{(z-t)}}$$ \
$$1 = A(z-t) + B(z+t)$$  
with solutions 
$$A=\frac{-1}{2t}$$ and $$ B=\frac{1}{2t} $$ 
substituting for t 
$$A=\frac{-1}{2t} = \frac{-1}{2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}(1+i)}= \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{6}}(1-i) $$ 
therefore
$$B= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}(1-i) $$

finally we get that

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{dz}{3+z^2}  =  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}} \Biggl( \int_0^\pi \frac{1-i}{z+\sqrt{3i}} - \int_0^\pi \frac{1-i}{z-\sqrt{3i}} \Biggl)$$ \

here is where I get confused I was hinted on using Cauchy Goursat but I am not sure why I can use this at this point or how to proceed from this point onwards. I mean I know going from 0 to $\pi$ and then from $\pi$ to 0 would be a closed path but it's not even the same integral so I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to prove this inequality. You're integrating a function whose maximum on $[0, \pi]$ is $1/3$. Multiplying this by the length of the interval gives an upper bound of $(1/3)(\pi - 0)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I still can figure out how how the maximum of the function is 1/3

Comment: ok got an idea from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dy9rAsOpxo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a subtle caveat with your question. The inequality

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dz}{z^2 + 3} \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$$

indicates that

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dz}{z^2 + 3} \in \mathbb{R}$$

otherwise an ordering can not be defined between the integral and $\pi/3$ because $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field. In this case, you do not even have to evaluate this integral at all in the complex setting.

We have the well known formula

$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1} = \arctan b - \arctan a$$

With $x = \sqrt{3} z/3$, you can proceed from here without using techniques from complex analysis like the Cauchy-Goursat's theorem. Wouldn't this be sufficient for your needs?

Or was there supposed to be some modulus operator $\mid \cdot \mid$ in the integral?

Comment: geez, hadn't considered that it had to equal a real. I can proceed with the integral that way and get 1/3 (arctan pi/√ 3 - arctan 0) since arc tan 0 = 0  i'm left with  1/3 (arc tan pi/√ 3 ) which is < 1/3(pi/2)  < (pi/3)

Comment: The integral evaluates to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \arctan \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{3}$. Hence, we just have to show that $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \arctan \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{3} \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$. Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{3}$, we have $\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{3} \leq \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{3}$. Clearly, this is true because if you look at the graph of $f(x) = \arctan x$, we have $\arctan x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{3}$.

Comment: Alternatively, we also have $\arctan x < x$ for all $x > 0$ which directly gives us the desired result $\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{3} < \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{3}$. :)

Comment: I just received an update on the exercise and yes there should be an absolute value there as you proposed initially, I could finally solve it.

Comment: Good to know that you finally solved the updated exercise with $\mid \cdot \mid$ it it. :) I assume you used the theorem described in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Modulus_of_Complex_Integral to do it, am I right?